# Loop resulting in: "TypeError: Undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, global-variables

I have made the following script:

```
//Declaring global variables

var difference = 6; //difference between two dates
var startdate = new Date(2015, 04, 04); //the start date
var startday = startdato.getDay(); //the weekday of the start date
var dateinterval = [startdate]; //declaring the date array
var days = [startday]; //declaring the weekday array

//Defining a date array (works fine)

for (var i=0; i < difference; i++){
   dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = dateinterval[0].setDate(datointerval[0].getDate() + i);
};

// Defining a weekday array using the date array (does not work)

for (var i=0; i < datointerval.length; i++){
days[days.length]
= dateinterval[i].getDay()
};
```

---

The above script returns the `TypeError: Undefined is not a function`. I don't get it.

I have declared the dateinterval variable in the beginning and thus is should be a global variable. Then I modify the dateinterval variable with the first loop.

However when using the global variable in the second loop it is as if the second loop only "sees" the variable defined in the beginning (which only has one date) and therefore all indexes above "0" becomes "undefined". I have established this by trying changing dateinterval[i] to dateinterval[0]. This works. If I change it to dateinterval[1] it results in the mentioned error.

What am I missing?

Comment: `datointerval` is a typo. You mention it a couple of times in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the first loop, where you assign the value returned by `setDate()` to the array which is the time in millis(So you have an error like `dateinterval[i].getDay is not a function`)

```
//Defining a date array (works fine)
for (var i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
    var dt = new Date(dateinterval[0]);
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + i);
    dateinterval[dateinterval.length] = dt;
};

// Defining a weekday array using the date array (does not work)
for (var i = 0; i < dateinterval.length; i++) {
    days[days.length] = dateinterval[i].getDay()
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/afxLyc4f/)

Comment: Thank you, Arun! I have been struggling for hours trying to figure it out by myself. What a relief that is finally working.